# Pokemon Go - Switching gmail accounts

Tags: pokemon-go

I downloaded and made my Pokemon Trainer Club account with an email address that did not have the permission to purchase or store any payment info on my account. I made a new Gmail account that would have the permissions to do so and would like to know if I am able to switch my accounts through the app to store the payment info through Google Play. I am using an Android device and both accounts are through Gmail.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the in-app purchase for the game are done through the Play store, which means the account that you use to log into the Play store is the one that will handle payments, and that means switching accounts in-game shouldn't do anything

Comment: It doesn't give me an option to switch gmail accounts through the app and I have Pokemon Go under My Apps and Games in my new email, so it should be registered just fine. It's all a bit convoluted to me.

Answer (score 1):

After trying out a few different solutions to this, I found that it is not on the app's side, but rather an issue with Google Play. Uninstalling the app completely and downloading it through the website (the app does not work I've found) under the other account will transfer it successfully, and this should work for all Google Play Games. Here is the website I found the solution from should anyone have the same issue. Happy Hunting!!!

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70215/change-gmail-account-to-make-in-app-purchase

Answer (score 0):

Open the Pokemon Go app, press the pokeball at the low center, go to Settings in the top right corner, scroll down and select the SIGN OUT option. Restart device, enter the game again and now you can choose the account you want. Google Play Games must be up to date.

Comment: I did this, made sure GP Games was up to date, but did not see an option to choose the email account to purchase with, only the previous email. I forgot to mention earlier I signed up through Pokemon Trainer's Club, not through Google, if that makes any difference.